# How to filter Realm Results by String

Tags: android, filter, realm

I want to filter the `RealmResult` with respect to the  name of persons whose name is "max" This is my `RealmResult`.

```
RealmResults  data = realm.where(Users.class).findAll();
```

but how to select the users with name `"max"` only?

Comment: Why do you ask a question if you know the answer ?

Comment: This is a Q/A  coz i did't find the answer in stackoverflow and thought it might help others coz it took me sometime to find in docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do so. Just use the `contains(String variableName,String filteringValueString)` method. In this case:

```
RealmResults<Users> data = realm.where(Users.class).contains("name", "max").findAll();
```

You can even sort the user with name "max" in the alphabetical order of their last name using `sort(String variableName,int sortingOrder)` method like this  :

```
RealmResults<Users> data = realm.where(Users.class).contains("name", "max").sort("lastName", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
```